# How Get the Special Character list from a HTML string

Tags: php, html, phpdocx

In my database I have saved,

```
<p>& sign test</p> <p><>greater than and less than</p>
```

I am using these for document download. I want replace these special characters `&` and `<>`  with  `&amp;` and `&lt;&gt;` respectively.

How can I detect special characters from the above html content?

Comment: Please show your code that you already tried.

Comment: php strip_tags() function used to get the text

Comment: Can You Explain More for Understand What you actually need

Comment: In tabel I have save above html content. but they not all html there are special characters, I want to firstly get the special characters and convert them to html. currently I am getting text, but I want to detect only special characters from that text, can I get some special character array from the text given.

Answer (score 1):

```
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
```

or you can use your custom function if you dont want html tag to convert into unicode :

```
$text = str_replace(array("&quot;", "&amp;"), array("\"", "&"), $text);
```

Comment: in my input it has html tags they are also converting to &lt; and &gt;

Comment: for above code you have presented I am printing the <p> tags also, I want to remove them.